# How to start using R (or free alternatives)?

Tags: regression, math-software, regression-analysis

How to start using software R to make regression analysis and forecasting?

Are there any other free software to work with this kind of analysis?

Answer (score 1):

R is free!  Go [here](http://www.r-project.org/) and download it plus there are manual on their site too.  R is also in linux repositories if you are a linux fellow.  You will go far by googling introduction to R.

Answer (score 1):

maybe, the datacamp website could help https://www.datacamp.com/courses/free-introduction-to-r

additionally, python is used commonly. You can learn the basics here: http://www.codecademy.com/